# Apache Httpd Custom ErrorDocument 404 When ProxyPass returned 404

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, errordocument

I have an Apache web server in front of another application server, using Proxy Pass. When the request to application returned error 404, I want to show custom error page from the web server not the one that come from application server. I have tried to setup the ErrorDocument 404 on the virtual host, but it doesn't work. How should I do this? Or this is not possible?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName servername
  DocumentRoot /somepath/
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/someapp/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/someapp/

  ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can avoid proxying for a specific directory by specifying a `!` in place of the proxy target.  Since it acts on a directory, move `error.html` into a subdirectory (we'll say `errors`), and:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName servername
  DocumentRoot /somepath/
  ProxyPass /errors !
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/someapp/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/someapp/
  ProxyErrorOverride On
  ErrorDocument 404 /errors/error.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe the config lack some details, but what I want is to catch the error 404 returned from the proxy pass and show the error.html instead.

Comment: Thanks, I found the way to override, I can just use the ProxyErrorOverride directive

Comment: @satyavirya Good catch, I'll add that to the answer for future searchers.

Comment: thanks for the hint to ProxyErrorOverride, but i found that there is a bug when using Apache 2.4 before 2.4.11 which should already be fixed: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53420   ... maybe the only workaround would be to reduce the proxytimeout?!

Comment: ```ProxyPass /errors !``` really helped me out!